# Looking for Node.js module that can parse function body for regex that is not commented out

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Say I have this function like so:

```
function foo(x,y,z){

 // x.bar();

 x.baz();

}
```

if I run  `foo.toString().match(/x.bar/)`, I will get the match that is commented out.

I am looking for a library that someone has written that can help me match the regex only if it's non commented out. Is there such a lib?

Comment: Sounds like it would help to run the file through a minifier first, and tell it to only strip out comments.

Comment: Not a bad idea, although a bit of cpu overhead I might want to avoid for this app. Also, I need to preserve line numbers, because I am printing stack traces that the user will need.

Comment: I wonder if there is a minifier that could strip out comments and fill with whitespace

Answer (score 2):

To remove/ignore  comments and preserve line numbers, you'd have to write something yourself that can parse/understand Javascript comments and probably turn them into whitespace so you could then run your regex.

But, note that the same function could be executed a lot of different ways such as:

```
x["bar"]()

var y = "bar"; 
x[y]();

x.bar.call(x);

y = x;
y.bar();
```

Or, not executed a bunch of ways like this:

```
if (false) {
    x.bar();
}

var str = "   x.bar();   "

return;
x.bar();
```

So it's kind of slippery slope to try to really figure out whether that specific function call is actually made by the code or not without actually running the code and directly monitoring the `.bar()` method.